# Is this subset closed, bounded, and compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I have started working on real analysis from Shurman's book.I got stucked on this question. Can you please help?

Is this subset closed, bounded, and compact?

$\{(x,y)\in R^2 :y−x^2 =0\}$

**Attempt:**

Closed - x can be anything between $(- \infty,\infty )$ and y can take values $[0,\infty )$ therefore I thought it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is closed, because it is $f^{-1}(\{0\})$, where $f(x,y)=y-x^2$, and because $f$ is continuous.

It is not bounded, because, for every $r>0$, there is some element of the set outside the ball centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $r$.

And since it is unbounded, it is not compact.

Comment: Jose,Thanks a lot for help. There are few points I couldn't clearly understand.

-Closed : Can you please help me in more details of assessing the closedness.
Bounded: Is it because f(x,y) is defined where x and y can be $\infty$?

Comment: @eldvin There's a standard General Topolgy theorem that asserts that, if $f$ is continuous and $B$ is closed, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed. It is unbounded because, if $r>0$, then $(r,r^2)$ belongs to your set but its distance from $(0,0)$ is greater than $r$; therefore, no ball centered at $(0,0)$ contains your set.